# How to deploy a file with Delphi to a shared directory path on Android?

Tags: android, delphi

I was asked this recently, and searched a broad range of sites, but none were useful to provide a direct answer to this issue.

I want to deploy a file alongside my app directly into the shared folders, specifically the documents folder `/storage/emulated/0/Documents`.

In order to deploy a file inside my app's private directory, we use `.\assets\internal` to provide the file that we will use, and inside the app we use `TPath.GetDocumentsPath` to read this file inside the internal folder of our app's private folder.

But how can I deploy a file alongside my app that, from Delphi, I would read from `TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath`? What is the path that I have to set in the "Project > Deployment" tab for that file?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't deploy files *directly* to the shared documents folder at app installation.  You will have to deploy files to your app's private folder only, and then at runtime your app can *copy* the files from its private folder to the shared documents folder as needed.